# mod_rewrite: subdomain to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, subdomain

So I have `mydomain.tld`, `www.mydomain.tld` and `res.mydomain.tld` all pointing to the same directory: `/var/www/mydomain`. In that directory, there's my codeigniter application.

So what I'm trying to do is to forward all requests made through `res.mydomain.tld` to a specific controller called `resources`.

What I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^res\.mydomain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/resources/$1 [L]
```

This produces a server error, my rewrite log doesn't provide any clues about why; it just shows some very weird logic being applied to the request string.

Any idea of why this isn't working?

Comment: What kind of server error, a 500 internal server error with the apache error page?

Comment: What does the error log say, if you're not getting useful info from the rewrite log?

Comment: hakre: yes.
Michael: just that the request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave your .htaccess was before.

In your routes.php

```
if($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]=="res.mydomain.tld"){
    $route['default_controller'] = "resources";
}else{
    //$route['default_controller'] = Your default controller...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You created a infinite loop. It keeps on rewriting, because the rules always match, and match again. Just add a rule like the following above your rule

```
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]
```

This will prevent any remaining rules underneath it from executing if the (already rewritten) url starts with index.php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `index.php` isn't matching and going into a rewrite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^res\.mydomain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/resources/$1 [L]
```

Comment: but shouldn't the [L] flag avoid further rewriting of the same request?

Comment: @Tom, no because it's not another rule being processed.  After the redirect to index.php, the same rule matches again and the redirect happens again. (and again and again)

Comment: the [L] prevent rules underneath the current one from being applied. But after it is done and the url has been rewritten, it starts the whole process again for the new url.